# How do you connect rails app with postgres database on app engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to deploy an app on Google App engine Flex with postgres.

My database.yml contains the following :

```
production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  socket: /cloudsql/[postgres_instance_name]
  database: pia-data
  timeout: 5000
  pool:     5
  username: postgres
  password: test
```

but I get the following error :

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
```

I tried with private IP and VPC, but the same error.
I don't know what I'm missing exactly to make it run, as it runs locally with 127.0.0.1 and cloud proxy.
Anybody had the same issue on GCP ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible?

Comment: App Engine Flex.
I have also 
`
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: [INSTANCE_NAME]
`

Comment: Try to replace the `socket:` to `host:` in `database.yaml`